# Convergence of mollifed Bochner integrable functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, bochner-spaces

I have a question about Spaces involving time from Evans' PDE book.

> Let $u \in L^2(0,T; H^1_0(U))$, with $u' \in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(U))$.

Could we show that $(u_\epsilon)' \to u'$ in $ L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(U))$, where $u_\epsilon = u *\eta_{\epsilon}$ and $\eta_\epsilon$ is a mollifer. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is the desired convergence in the $L^2$ sense (instead of $L^2_{\text{loc}}$)?

Comment: @Pedro I think it is. However, if you have any idea of convergence in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$, it would be also helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the idea in the proof of Thm 2 of Sec 5.9 can help.